# How can I determine the hyperlink of a currently opened documentation page programmatically?

Tags: front-end, notebooks

Every pages in the documentation has a hyperlink. Here are some examples:

```
"paclet:ref/NotebookRead"
"paclet:guide/GraphStylingAndLabeling"
"paclet:tutorial/ListsOverview"
```

Well, my question is:

If I open a docs page, then how can I get the hyperlink of it programmatically?

### my tries

Till now, I can get the `NotebookInformation` of documentation notebooks (if it exist):

```
Select[NotebookInformation /@ 
     Notebooks[], ("DocumentType" /. #) == "Help" &]
```

The output might be:

```
{{"FileName" -> 
   FrontEnd`FileName[{$RootDirectory, "C:", "Program Files", 
 "Wolfram Research", "Mathematica", "9.0", "Documentation", 
 "ChineseSimplified", "System", "Tutorials"}, "ListsOverview.nb", 
     CharacterEncoding -> "CP936"], 
  "FileModificationTime" -> 3.56977*10^9, 
 "WindowTitle" -> "List - Wolfram Mathematica", 
"MemoryModificationTime" -> 3.58634*10^9, 
  "ModifiedInMemory" -> True, "DocumentType" -> "Help", 
 "StyleDefinitions" -> {NotebookObject[
    FrontEndObject[LinkObject["d5i_shm", 3, 1]], 46]}}}
```

But I don't know what to do next. The correspondence between the `FileName` and hyperlink seems to be confusing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not very sophisticated but works so far:

```
nb = (Select[Notebooks[], ("DocumentType" /. NotebookInformation[#]) == "Help" &])

"uri" /. Options[Options[#, TaggingRules][[1, 2]], Metadata][[1, 2]] & /@ nb
```

> ```
> {"tutorial/SettingUpFunctionsWithOptionalArguments"}
> ```

Please tell me if this works for you too.

**Edit**

Shorter one:

```
nb = (Select[Notebooks[], ("DocumentType" /. NotebookInformation[#]) == "Help" &])
Cases[Options /@ nb, HoldPattern["uri" -> x_] :> x, Infinity]
```

> ```
> {"guide/Calculus"}
> ```

Comment: It works, thanks for helping :). And +1 for digging into the notebook expression.

Comment: @pheiztu I'm glad it works. Please take a look at an edit, this seems to be shorter way.

Comment: Cool, I wish I can cast another vote for it.

Comment: +1 although Using `NotebookGet` on documentation interface often freezes for me.

Comment: @Kuba Well, ok, I just think "accept" = "another vote" :p

Comment: @Liam I realised that `NotebookGet` is redundant so you can skip it. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
"paclet:ref/" <> FileBaseName[Last[FileNameSplit[NotebookFileName[
SelectedNotebook[]]]]]
```

Will return a string of the paclet of the currently selected notebook document iff it is a reference. Change the "ref" for guide if needed for guides.

Comment: +1, it looks better for me :) but you need to place it in palette or use it after selecting automatically the Help Notebook because now it is not handy I think. I can copy a link directly if I have to put it in Help Notebook :)