# Capturing an F1

Tags: notebooks, keyboard, documentation, eventhandler

I teach an *Intro to Mathematica* course, and one of the things I try to reinforce early on is just how helpful Mathematica's help is.  In the very first lab for the course, I even give the students a randomly selected command (from among simple ones like `PrimeQ`, `IntegerDigits`, etc.) and ask them to tell me what that command does. As of right now, they get this question right if they correctly explain what the given command does.

What I'd like to do is make sure they are actually going to the help.  Is there some way to capture an **F1** key press within an `EventHandler` or something similar?

Comment: If it helps, ``MemberQ[Contexts[], "DocumentationSearch`"]`` will only start returning True after the documentation search has been used at least once in the session ...  Otherwise I think it's really the students' responsibility to listen to something as simple as "use the documentation!"

Comment: Trying to make sure they press F1 may not be such a good idea... what if they go to help by typing ? or by searching google? If you want to make sure they go to help, ask a question like: how many items are there in the examples subsection of the help page?

Comment: So you are giving them notebook with questions and you want to check this?

Comment: [related: link to the currently opened help page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31047/5478)

Comment: @bills: I actually would like to make sure they visit the help, however they do it.  It's just that I explain the F1 option to them in class, which is why I would expect most would go that route.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could add a trap to `` Documentation`HelpLookup `` which is called when F1 is pressed:

```
Unprotect[Documentation`HelpLookup];
Documentation`HelpLookup[link_String, nb_, lang_String, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Block[{$inblock = True},
   lookedup[link] = True;
   Documentation`HelpLookup[link, nb, opts]] /; ! TrueQ[$inblock]
```

You can add whatever code you want. As an example I assign a downvalue to `lookedup` so the searched expressions can be viewed with `? lookedup`

Note: The `Block[{$in = True}, ...] /; ! TrueQ[$in]` construct is the [Villegas-Gayley](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39711/862) technique for injecting code into built-in functions.

Comment: It seems it is called whenever documentation page is opened. So not only with F1 but also when you dig throught `See also...` or if you open documentation in menu.

Comment: Heh, poor Mr.Wizard... he's gonna lose a grade by wasting time [counting leaves](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41725/how-to-open-directly-the-help-reference-window-from-a-notebook/41745?noredirect=1#comment124827_41745) :D

Comment: @rm-rf, ha ha. I didn't see that question 2 days ago, I was hoping everyone would be stunned by my spelunking skills, now it just looks like I'm copying from higher rep users ;-)

Comment: This is great, but is there any way to store the lookedup variable between sessions? The students will do the lab, close it, send it to me, then I open it.  Any way I can still find out what help items they've visited?

Comment: @SteveD You can use `NotebookEventActions` and send the e-mail yourself. Or just use the trigger to store the value :)

Comment: @SimonWoods Lol... I think a lot of people here learned it from [Todd Gayley's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16483/5) a while ago.

Comment: @Kuba: but how does one store a value in a notebook? That is something I don't know how to do, and haven't gotten the answers to fully work over at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/saving-data-inside-a-notebook-so-that-i-dont-have-to-run-it-again

Comment: @SteveD, try using `InputNotebook` in place of `EvaluationNotebook` in those answers

Comment: @SteveD "but how does one store a value in a notebook?" --> use `TaggingRules`! This is better than making up an option like `Stored` and it was recommended in the past as the solution to use.  1. Check the value of `CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "lookups"}]`.  If it's "Inherited", then initialize it: `CurrentValue[SelectedNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "lookups"}] = {}`.  Then keep appending `AppendTo[CurrentValue[
  SelectedNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "lookups"}], "asd"]`.  When they save the notebook, this gets saved with it.

Comment: @Kuba see my comment above, and here's the ref: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1113/12

Comment: @Kuba, done....

Comment: @SimonWoods Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

This is my idea.

If you give them the notebook with questions just put the following code in the cell with a question text (as `InlineCell` <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd>)

```
DynamicModule[{},
 DynamicWrapper["test",
   Refresh[
    help = DeleteDuplicates @ Join[help, "WindowTitle" /. NotebookInformation /@
    Select[Notebooks[], ("DocumentType" /. NotebookInformation[#]) == "Help" &]]
    , UpdateInterval -> .5]]
 , Initialization :> (help = {};)]
```

Then `EvaluateInPlace` this with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or via menu.

There is now variable `help` that will show you which documentation pages were opened.

Test this with

```
Dynamic@help
```

> ```
> {Dynamic - Wolfram Mathematica, Animate - Wolfram Mathematica,...}
> ```

You can work on this to get the date etc. The only problem is it will show a message that the notebook contains dynamic content.